# how can one create a purge command

Tags: discord.js

so I have been searching far and wide on the internet and found nothing to help me code a purge command.
how can one create a purge command? for example when a user says: ":purge (amount)"

if anyone can help me then it would be great because I spent literally hours and still can't find working one. I know this is a bit much but I don't know where else to find and ask.

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you said that you have used `client.on("message")`, you can use the following code for your discord bot under the main javascript file.

```js
client.on("message", async(message, args, cmd, client, Discord) => {
  if (command == "purge");
  if (message.member.roles.cache.has('Role ID')) {
    if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Number not defined");
    if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Not a real number");

    if (args[0] > 100) return message.reply('I can only delete a maximum of 100 mesages');
    if (args[0] < 1) return message.reply('You cannot delete less than 1 message');

    await message.channel.messages.fetch({
      limit: args[0]
    }).then(messages => {
      message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
    })

  } else {
    message.channel.send('Incorrect permissions.')
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all welcome to stack overflow!
So a clear/purge would require an additional argument which will read the number of messages you want to delete ( i guess you would already know that ).

So first of all you would require an if condition aruond the function in order to all only administrations/moderators to use this command which you can do by using `if(message.member.roles.cache.has('Role ID')){}`
After that you would require a few more if statements in case the person doesn't mention the number/ wrong input or mentions over 100 messages ( you can only delete a maximum of 100 messages at a time )

Now the thing you were waiting for, the function you can use for purge/clear is

```js
await message.channel.messages.fetch({
  limit: args[0]
}).then(messages => {
  message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
})
```

Comment: I think it works, but since I'm dumb I think I messed it up the code that I used is 
client.on("message", async message => {
   const args = message.content.split(" ")
          if(message.content === ":purge"){
            await message.channel.messages.fetch({
  limit: args[0]
}).then(messages => {
  message.channel.bulkDelete(messages)
})
}
})

and sorry for being dumb :(
idk how to fix